# Magento 2 Extension Scrutinizer Dependencies Error

Tags: magento2, code-analysis

I'm trying to run some auto-code-review in scrutinizer-ci for a new extension, the problem is that the builder can't find these composer dependencies:

- "magento/framework": "~100.0",
- "magento/module-catalog": "~100.0",
- "magento/module-store": "~100.0",
- "magento/module-theme": "~100.0",

These are my module dependencies and I don't want to remove them, so anyone knows if there is a way to "hack" dependencies resolution in scrutinizer or if my composer.json file is wrong?

Here is my entire composer.json file

```
{
  "name": "mauronigrele/setuptools",
  "description": "Mauro Nigrele - Setup Tools",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Mauro Nigrele",
      "email": "mauro.nigrele@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    "magento/framework": "~100.0",
    "magento/module-catalog": "~100.0",
    "magento/module-store": "~100.0",
    "magento/module-theme": "~100.0",
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "MauroNigrele\\SetupTools\\": "MauroNigrele/SetupTools"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Composer currently would not have any knowledge where to find `magento/framework`, etc as it would only look on packagist for them. To fix you would need to add the below to your composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://repo.magento.com/"
    }
]
```

and then use login details linked to your Magento account - see [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html) for details on how to create it.

Comment: Thanks for response. I understand your point I could do it that way locally but I can't figure out how to send such information to scrutinizer. (if I remove dependencies build works fine but some bugs brings up due to dependencies). - BTW I take the opportunity to thank you for your speedster extension! it's present in all my M1 stores since it was released!

Comment: No probs and you might also want to checkout Speedster Advanced. You might have to ping @jcowie for scrutinizer advice.

Comment: thanks again, and sure we use Speedster Advanced most of the time.